# yum-cron updates dotnet SDK too agressively

Tags: .net-core, centos7, yum

I set up automatic nightly updates for our CentOS 7 build servers using `yum-cron`. They are not production machines, so this shouldn't bite me -- I thought.

I ran into an issue with `dotnet` though. We have a fixed version to compile against in `global.json` and we want it to keep it that way to control the process. The idea was that new versions of `dotnet` are going to be installed alongside the old ones, but that's not the case, unfortunately: what I see at the machine is only the current version of SDK, not the old one our applications depend on in build time:

```
[user@machine ~]$ dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.603 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

I don't want to turn the auto-updates off. How to set it up so the SDKs we depend on stays present?

Comment: What is the yum-cron command that you're running? (forgive my ignorance if this is a simple or stupid question, I'm an Ubuntu user so I only have experience with apt)

Comment: What you are seeing is a design limitation in `global.json` - it's not compatible with in-place upgrades. There's an attempt to address this in newer versions: https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/71

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust yum-cron's frequency, at least a little bit. Would once-a-week update work for you? If so, look at `DAYS_OF_WEEK` in `/etc/sysconfig/yum-cron`.

Comment: Thanks, but that would still require me to babysit all the repositories and update their pins after any upgrade breaks the builds. I would like to teach yum to not remove the previous SDKs somehow, only to apply security fixes to them.

Comment: "not remove the previous SDKs somehow, only to apply security fixes to them".. that might be a problem. The security fixes are only released as a new SDK. So you can't stay at the older SDK *and* get the security fixes. If you want to keep on installing additional versions, though, look at the `installonlypkgs` option in yum.conf.